# Initializing NSArray of numbers

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsnumber

I have an non-mutable array that only needs to have numbers.  How would I have to initialize this?

I have it like below right now but I'm thinking there has to be a better way. Can we do it like in C++?  Something like this `int list[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};` would that have any impact on the application?

```
myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], nil];
```

Also, if I had a need for an array of arrays with only numbers, how would this look like? I'm new to obj-c and looking around online I've seen conflicting answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is non-mutable and only contains numbers just use the C array directly. There is nothing wrong with using C arrays in Objective-C, and in your case an `NSArray` is just unneeded overhead.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was hopping for.  What about a two dimensional array? could we do it in C syntax also?

Answer (score 8):

Not yet, but soon:

http://blog.ablepear.com/2012/02/something-wonderful-new-objective-c.html

Update: The new syntax is:

```
@[ @(20), @(10) ]
```

The `@[]` creates an array, the `@(number)` makes an NSNumber that can go in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a category to NSArray:

```
@implementation NSArray ( ArrayWithInts )

+(NSArray*)arrayWithInts:(const int[])ints count:(size_t)count
{
    assert( count > 0 && count < 100 ) ;    // just in case

    NSNumber * numbers[ count ] ;
    for( int index=0; index < count; ++index )
    {
        numbers[ index ] = [ NSNumber numberWithInt:ints[ index ]] ;
    }

    return [ NSArray arrayWithObjects:numbers count:count ] ;
}
@end
```

`countof()` looks like this:

```
#define countof(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
```

Use like this:

```
const int numbers[] = { 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0 } ;  
NSArray * array = [ NSArray arrayWithInts:numbers count:countof(numbers) ] ) ;
```

Or you could just use @CRD's suggestion above...